# Pivot table in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a pivot table like so:

[image: Table of content]

And I would like to get it like this:

[image: Result of pivot table]

I need to make a pivot table that shows the number of products sold by country. A person should understand where each product is sold most.

I can only get something like this:

[image: What I get]

Comment: Your bottom table is a non sequitur.  Where did your row labels come from, and why aren't you using Product there?  And if you do that, how is the result different from what you need?

Answer (score 0):

How about change the PivotTable to Classic PivotTable?

**Right Click** the Pivot Table- Select **PivotTable Options**- under **Display** Tab check the option **Classic PivotTable layout(enables dragging of fields in the grid)**:

[image]